# Problem in orientation in iPad app

Tags: iphone, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am creating a application in which I can need to play a video which I do by mpmovieplayer controller .Now i nee to do this for both orientation .But the frame doesnt get set properly .

The code is as follws

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];

    NSURL *temp = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Floating" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:temp]; 
    mpviewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    mpviewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    mpviewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile; 
    mpviewController.view.userInteractionEnabled= NO;
    mpviewController.moviePlayer.fullscreen= YES;
    mpviewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];

    [self.view addSubview:mpviewController.view]; 

}
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    currentOrientation = interfaceOrientation;
    //[self SetInterface];

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        mpviewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        mpviewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);




    return YES;
}
```

I dont know where I am wrong.Please let me know for any chages to make in code. So as to get proper orientation.

Ragards Abhi

Comment: @luzhin thanks for editing the question, actually i dont know how to add our code with the question thats why this happened.

Comment: no problem you can use these HTML tags `<pre> insert here your code</pre>` to add code in your question

Comment: @luzin thanks will do that from next question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**
I believe you don't need to resize the mpviewController as it will resize it self alone.
you should only set the -

**Second**

In the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation you only set the supported directions  in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {  
        return YES;
}
```

If it dose not do it you change the view properties in -

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
     //do what you want for portrait
     }else{
     //do what you want for landscape
    }

}
```

Comment: Just *do not* use a private method to do it: setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO

Comment: No i am stil facing the same issue if u can provide the code snipet it would be great .

Answer (score 1):

you should only return either YES or NO in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method, it's called by framework only to get the information about the supported orientation in your controller, Read the apple documentation for the same.

you need to register for the orientation change notifictaion

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Implement your `orientationChanged:` method.

```
//********** ORIENTATION CHANGED **********
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"Orientation  has changed: %d", [[note object] orientation]);
   //Put your code here from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
}
```

Not forget it to remove .

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Here are some link

[Device orientation - autorotate?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2588)

[Orientation Changed Notification](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/notifications/orientation-change-notification)

Comment: it would be great if u can provide some code snippet as i tried but result is same even i went through the link u suggested .Just make the chages in code i proivided in the question and post it in your asnwer it would be great help as i  am really stuck at this point .

Answer (score 0):

No need to change any codings .. simple insert the following codings to the application , it will automatically detect the orientation...

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];                         
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];      
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"sharkdivertrailer" ofType:@"mp4"];   
NSURL  *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];      
        MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];     
        theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
        [theMovie play];  
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];       
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```